# google analytics and CRM integration

Tags: google-analytics, integration, crm

On this page, https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/crm-integration#summary-of-crm-data-integration-options-for-google-analytics ,

at the end of the table, for measure "Your Google Analytics profile based on user Id only shows activity for authenticated users". What does authenticated users mean in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will try and clear this up.   Normally when you send info to Google Analytics you use Cid think of it as a session id.   So if I am on your website using chrome I get a session id and everything is sent using that cid.   Then if for some dumb reason I start Internet Explorer well I get a different session id and am sending hits using a different cid.   So Google analytics sees me as two different sessions.

Now if your website has a login function.  I login and you send my login id as uid.  Then for some unknown reason I start internet explore and login to your website again I have a user id.   I am authenticated to your website and you send and the Uid for my activity both on chrome and internet explorer will be recorded as the same person.

First option logs as to separate sessions, second Google Analytics will detect that it is in fact the same person over several sessions.

The authenticated user is the users authentication or login on your website or application.

Comment: What about those not logged in? Do they continue to use the old method? Or get lumped together under one dummy session? Or just not appear at all? Also does this affect all reports/screens or are there specific reports/screens only that are only used for the authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an ETL tool for combining the data from a Google Analytics account and a CRM software. The reason for doing that is so you can normalize the data.
The authentication is typically handled by the ETL vendor through API access key or OAuth log in.

There're a lot of tools that do this, Fivetran, Acho, Stitch and others.